# Does MySQL Enterprise Backup work across Operating Systems?

Tags: mysql, backup

The problem with testing is that one can never be sure (it may seem to work and then you find some thing changed later). A definitive statement from the vendor would definitely be helpful (I cannot seem to find any).

I am thinking about running MySQL Enterprise Backup between MacOS and Liunx OSes

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Enterprise Backup (MEB) is designed to create a point-in-time snapshot of data but only backs up data locally. If the dataset is relatively small, try setting up an NFS share and run MySQL Enterprise Backup with the NFS share as the Target. Of course, there may be some risk involved.

Please check out these links on this subject for further research on MEB

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.6/en/meb-backup-streaming.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.6/en/meb-backup-single-file.html
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,409106,410496#msg-410496

Using MEB with data on server with MacOS and Linux OS on the Target Server? One can only guess. Personally, if I had to port mysql data from one OS to another I would recommend this:

- Run mysqldump from MacOS to sqldump.sql
- Install mysql on Linux
- Load sqldump.sql into Linux
- Setup replication between servers

  - MacOS running mysql as Master
  - Linux running mysql as Slave

From here, just install MEB on the Linux Box (For free version, use [XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/)) and run your MEB backups locally on the Linux.